# How to obtain the content of a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I have a config file with this content:

**config_scrm.sh**

```
CDT_TRIGGER='69'
SR_TRIGGER='165'
```

In the main script I need to insert the content of CDT_TRIGGER (which is 69) in a variable called TRIGGER. The only thing I have to know I should get that exact variable content is another (local) variable called ELM='CDT'

So, in the main script, I execute:

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source config_scrm.sh

(some calculations to obtain the value of variable ELM)

ELM='CDT'
```

I need TRIGGER to be 69.

If ELM='SR', I would need TRIGGER to be 165. And so on, there are way more values than showed in this excerpt.

---

What is not working:

```
MYSTRING='_TRIGGER'
TRIGGER=${$ELM$MYSTRING}
```

or

```
TRIGGER=`echo "$ELM$MYSTRING"`
```

or

```
TRIGGER=`$(echo "$ELM$MYSTRING")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `$ELM$MYSTRING` expands to the name you want, `TRIGGER=${$ELM$MYSTRING}` doesn't work because here you need parameter expansion to occur twice: "inner" variables first, then the "outer" one.

Your tries with command substitution would make little more sense if you actually used the "outer" `$` to *try* to trigger additional parameter expansion; but even then they would fail for similar reason as the above.

Well, you *can* have parameter expansion in two separate steps. You need `eval` for this:

```
eval 'TRIGGER=$'"$ELM$MYSTRING"
```

At first the variables within `""` are expanded normally, everything within `''` is left intact. Then `eval` performs additional parsing of the resulting string which is now exactly `TRIGGER=$CDT_TRIGGER`. The solution is portable, although you should be careful with `eval`. Please see [*Why should `eval` be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659)

In Bash there's a safer (yet not portable) way to do what you want:

```
wholename=$ELM$MYSTRING    # we need this in a single variable
TRIGGER=${!wholename}
```

<sub>Side note: consider [lowercase names for your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).</sub>

Comment: Since the ${!wholename} version is working perfectly, I'll stick to it. Regards.